# MessageConverter gets LinkedHashMap instead of regular object as a input

Tags: java, spring

I have question regarding message converters in spring.
I have following controller with function that should return JSON in regular case, but should return XML if there is exception, so I wanted to write custom message converter:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("status")
public class StatusControler
{
@RequestMapping(value="/get", produces = {"text/json", "text/xml"}) 
@ResponseBody
public void getStatus(@RequestBody String reqBody, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res)
     throws BaseAppException {
 /*
     Throws exception
 */
}
```

Exception is then handled by ExceptionHandler (XMLResponse is annotated with javax @XML accessors):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(BaseAppException .class)
@ResponseBody
public XMLResponse handleBaseException(HttpServletResponse response, final BaseAppException ex) {
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    XMLResponse ramloadResponse = new XMLResponse(ex);
    return ramloadResponse;
}
```

And afterwards passed to my message converter, that has following writeInternal (LOGGER is slf4j instance):

```
@Override
protected void writeInternal(Object t, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    LOGGER.info(t.getClass().toString());
}
```

Now in writeInternal I get LinkedHashMap, which is JSON of XMLResponse instance. Is there a way I can get XMLResponse here? I wanted to check class of response, and if it's XMLResponse marshall it to xml, and in any other case - to JSON

Comment: For future generations: Issue was that in Exception handler there was unsupported exception thrown. It resulted in no info in logs, and result object was auto marshalled to JSON.